# Ubuntu not loading on restart

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I have two hard disks:
Disk A, where Windows is installed; and Disk B, where Ubuntu is installed. 
Whenever I restart my PC, only Windows is loading and there is no trace of Ubuntu.

Comment: As you said these are two separate hard drives, check HDD boot priority settings in the BIOS. BTW could you add more info about brand/motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're describing your issue makes me believe grub hasn't been installed properly. If your ubuntu install is completely new, then you could just reinstall it. But here when you choose how you want to install ubuntu, make sure to select "something else". This will prompt a menu where you can select specific drives and also a location for your boot loader to be installed. [More information here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

Anyway if you don't wish to reinstall ubuntu, then you need to manually install it. There are various of guides on the internet that provides information on this, just a quick google search. Good luck.